# Is this expression right?

Tags: php

```
$tagstring = "search,google,searchengine,engine,web,reference,searchengines,internet,research,tools";

if((!empty($tagstring)) && ($tagstring < 10)){ //insert to mysql

} //end function
```

my question is will this eliminate `empty` resutl and do not insert if `$tagstring` is less than 10

my doubt is do I need to use `$tagstring < 10` or `$tagstring > 10` ?? I want minimum 10 or more tags on database

Comment: What do you mean, "Less than 10?" Fewer than 10 items in the list?

Comment: actually this one got only 10...I need to keep it minimum 10 or higher

Comment: What happens when you have an entry with *blanks*? i.e. `foo,bar,,,bat`

Comment: actually I forgot about explode stuff..well

Comment: @limo: be sure to **upvote and accept** good answers to your questions. You've never upvoted answers, which doesn't exactly encourage folks to answer your questions. It's how the reputation system works on StackOverflow.

Comment: actually I am not logged in so I cant vote...but sure will accept right answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$parts=explode(",",$tagstring);
// Cleaning up blank tags
foreach($parts as $k=>$v){
if($v==""){
unset($parts[$k]);
}
}

if(!empty($tagstring) && count($parts) >= 10){ 
//insert to mysql
}
```

This will check if the tags string isn't empty and the tags are 10 or more based on commas.

Bonus: cleaning up empty tags like : `foo,,,,,bar`

Comment: i don't know what he actually wants, in the question he says that tags are supposed to be less than 10, in his comments he says that the minimum is 10 but can be heigher....

Comment: well that was a confusion which I need to use < or >

Answer (score 0):

or maybe

```
strlen($tagstring) < 10
```

Comment: i believe he needs to count the tags not the whole tags string as it is.

Comment: I think then will be better using array?

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear on the question's first revision. It simply said "if string less than 10".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($tagstring) && substr_count(",",$tagstring) >= 10 ) {  
    //insert into mysql  
} else {
    //don't insert
}
```